# Slide somente com html e css

Tags: html5, css3

Gostaria de saber se e possível fazer um slide fazer um slide igual a desse site [aqui](http://www.locall.com.br/)
porem somente com `HTML` e `CSS` o slide que eu quero fazer seria esse aqui da imagem e vocês podem velos funcionando neste site que mencionei acima logo na home

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se tiverem algum link que possa me ajudar a solucionar agradeço também pois estou pesquisando muito e não acho nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acho que você está procurando por uma **gallery**, e não um **slider**, mas, de qualquer maneira, [aqui](http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/09/10-pure-css3-image-galleries-and-sliders/) existem 10 opções bem bacanas. Eu já usei a última, [CSS image enlarger gallery](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-image-enlarger.html), em um projeto, e ficou bem bacana.

Para fins de aprendizado, a Smashing Magazine tem um tutorial bem completo sobre isso que pode ser visto [aqui](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/).